# Spring java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in CCTOR

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, reflection

I am writting simple app using Spring and Hibernate using following beans definition xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="hibernateConfiguration" class="pl.wicia.projector.database.DBConfiguration" scope="prototype">
       <constructor-arg name="path" value="pl/wicia/projector/database/cfg.xml"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="pl.wicia.projector.database.HibernateSessionFactory" scope="prototype">
       <constructor-arg name="dbConfig" ref="hibernateConfiguration"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Now, I wanted to create data base configuration wrapper using injection by constructor-args:

```
package pl.wicia.projector.database;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class DBConfiguration {

    private Configuration configuration;

    public DBConfiguration(String path){
        this.configuration = new Configuration(); <--- this throws Exsception
        this.configuration.configure(path);
    }

    public Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }
}
```

And this line produces following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateConfiguration' defined in class path resource [pl/wicia/projector/spring/db_beans.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [pl.wicia.projector.database.DBConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
    at pl.wicia.projector.main.Projector.main(Projector.java:23)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [pl.wicia.projector.database.DBConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:86)
    at pl.wicia.projector.database.DBConfiguration.<init>(DBConfiguration.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 25 more
```

This is how I create my beans:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("pl/wicia/projector/spring/db_beans.xml");
DBConfiguration config = (DBConfiguration)context.getBean("hibernateConfiguration");
```

Any idea what is happening? :)

Comment: For what it's worth, 100% of this configuration can simply be eliminated by using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont' have `javax.transaction.SystemException` on your runtime classpath. This can be fixed by adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

dependency to your `pom.xml` if you use `Maven`. However there might be more serious problems with dependencies in your app if you are missing such essential class. Even if you fix it you might deal with the real situation which caused `javax.transaction.SystemException` to be thrown.